# How to move "Get Started" to articles in pkgdown

Tags: r, pkgdown

Usually, pkgdown websites have a "Get Started" section in the navbar.

However, user feedback I had is that people only look at the examples in the readme, then click on the articles, without even noticing this section.

The "Get Started" article comes from the vignette with the same name as the package (cf. https://pkgdown.r-lib.org/reference/build_articles.html#get-started).

**Is there a way to move the "Get started" navbar item to an article named "Get started"?**

Related: https://github.com/r-lib/pkgdown/issues/1405

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Hadley's advice in the referenced link I created a fresh package named `foo`, added two toy vignettes `foo` and `bar` and moved the `"Get started"` vignette from the `navbar` to the `articles` section using this `_pkgdown.yml`, i.e. following the [docs](https://pkgdown.r-lib.org/reference/build_site.html#navigation-bar) remove `intro` from the `navbar` structure and add the get started vignette under the `articles` section:

```
url: ~
template:
  bootstrap: 5

navbar:
  structure:
    left:  [reference, articles, tutorials, news]
    right: [search, github]
  components:
    articles:
      text: Articles
      menu:
      - text: Get started
        href: articles/foo.html
      - text: Other
        href: articles/bar.html
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But does this mean that you cannot use the `articles:` root key in `_pkgdown.yml` anymore?