# How to list "Get Started" vignette under both "Get Started" and "Articles" in pkgdown site for R package?

Tags: r, pkgdown

This is similar to [How to move "Get Started" to articles in pkgdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74891236/how-to-move-get-started-to-articles-in-pkgdown), but I want the article sharing the name of the package to be listed both under "Get Started" and under the "Articles" list.

Simply listing the vignette under the articles list in `_pkgdown.yml` doesn't seem to force it to show up there:

```
articles:
- title: Articles
  navbar: ~
  contents:
  - mypackage
  - othervignette
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can just leave the vignette sharing the package-name as-is with the package name, and then also manually specify it under the articles list like this in the `_pkgdown.yml` file:

```
navbar:
  structure:
    left: [intro, articles, reference, news]
  components:
    articles:
      text: Articles
      menu:
      - text: Introduction
        href: articles/mypackage.html
      - text: other vignette
        href: articles/othervignette.html
```